How to check if a list of inputted users are in a list of multiple accounts?
I'm trying to create a process that will iterate through a list of inputted users, use that list to see if those inputted users are in a list of account groups. And the account groups consist of a list of users.
Hopefully that makes sense. I will try to be more clear in the example
Example:
users_inputted = ['Bob', 'Joe', 'Mary']
accounts = ['Nike', 'Apple', 'Microsoft']

Nike = ['John', 'Mary', 'Bob']
Apple = ['Bob', 'Joe', 'Mark']
Microsoft = ['Jack', 'Bob', 'Mary']

for people in users_inputted:
    for groups in accounts:
        if people in groups:
            print(f"The User {people} is in {groups}")
        else:
            print(f"The User {people} is not in {groups}")

I would like my desired output to be something like:
The User Bob is in Nike
The User Bob is in Apple
The User Bob is in Microsoft
The User Joe is not in Nike
The User Joe is in Apple
The User Joe is not in Microsoft
The User Mary is in Nike
The User Mary is not in Apple
The User Mary is in Microsoft

where it's iterating through each user to check if they're in the group. However the output I'm getting is:
The User Bob is in Microsoft
The User Bob is in Microsoft
The User Bob is in Microsoft


When you do accounts = ['Nike', ... You're setting strings.  Try defining the companies and then doing, accounts = [Nike, Apple, Microsoft] (note they're not in quotes).  That won't solve it, but then all you need is to figure how to switch {groups} for the index that accounts is in..

I ran the code you posted. All I got was lots of "not in" messages, not the output you show. Your code is looking for substrings, and Bob is not a substring of Microsoft.

Did you consider using a dictionary keyed on account name?
